# Output streaming with PHP ob_start & ob_get_clean

Tags: php, ob-start, ob-get-contents

I have a script that `echo` out content in a php script and resulting in a very large file, e.g. 100MB

Currently I use the following way to capture the output and write to another file

```
ob_start();
require_once 'dynamic_data.php'; // echo 100MB data
$data = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents($path, $data);
```

Are there any easy way to re-write the above program (better not touching `dynamic_data.php` as it is hard to re-factor) so it can stream the output to the file directly without saving the content in the memory?

Comment: Instead of echoing and recapturing the output can't you add the file operations directly in `dymanic_data.php` without echoing? Any constraints in doing this ?

Comment: Because it is more easy to loop/echo using PHP as the template language instead of print to file directly. Also, I can reuse the same script for web output.

Answer (score 4):

The [`ob_start` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) provides a workaround for this. You need to pass in a `$output_callback` and a `$chunk_size`.

Say you set `$chunk_size` to 1MB. Then every 1MB of buffered output data, your `$output_callback` will be called with this data and you can flush it to disk (meanwhile the output buffer is implicitly flushed).

```
$output_callback = function($data) {
   //$buffer contains our 1MB of output

   file_put_contents($path, $data);

   //return new string buffer
   return "";
}

//call $output_callback every 1MB of output buffered.
ob_start($output_callback, 1048576);

require_once 'dynamic_data.php';

//call ob_clean at the end to get any remaining bytes 
//(implicitly calls $output_callback final time)
ob_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`proc_open`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) and invoke the PHP interpreter with this file as argument. This will not store the data in memory but it'll create another process.

```
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("file", $path, "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("file", $path, "a") // stderr is a file to write to
);

$process = proc_open('php dynamic_data.php', $descriptorspec, $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    // $pipes now looks like this:
    // 0 => writeable handle connected to child stdin
    // 1 => readable handle connected to child stdout
    // Any error output will be appended to /tmp/error-output.txt

    fclose($pipes[0]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    $return_value = proc_close($process);
}
?>
```